# How to create a method that takes a Generic base type

Tags: c#, generics

I have something similar to the following, but I cannot provide `House` or `Farm` objects to the `PrintShelterAddress` method:

```
public interface IAnimal { };
public interface IDomesticAnimal : IAnimal { };
public interface IHouseAnimal : IDomesticAnimal { };
public interface IFarmAnimal : IDomesticAnimal { };

public class Animal : IAnimal { }
public class DomesticAnimal : Animal, IDomesticAnimal { }
public class Lion : Animal { }
public class Cat : DomesticAnimal, IHouseAnimal { }
public class Horse : DomesticAnimal, IFarmAnimal { }

public interface IAnimalShelter<T> where T : IDomesticAnimal { String Address { get; set; } };
public interface IHouse : IAnimalShelter<IHouseAnimal> { };
public interface IFarm : IAnimalShelter<IFarmAnimal> { };

public class AnimalShelter<T> : IAnimalShelter<T> where T : IDomesticAnimal { public String Address { get; set; } }
public class House : AnimalShelter<IHouseAnimal>, IHouse { }
public class Farm : AnimalShelter<IFarmAnimal>, IFarm { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintShelterAddress(new House() { Address = "MyHouse" });  // Error: argument type 'House' is not assignable to parameter type 'IAnimalShelter<IDomesticAnimal>'

        // This makes sense as House is a IAnimalShelter<IHouseAnimal>
        // and IHouseAnimal cannot be cast to its parent IDomesticAnimal
        IAnimalShelter<IDomesticAnimal> nonDescriptShelter = new House();  // InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'House' to type 'IAnimalShelter`1[IDomesticAnimal]'.
    }

    static void PrintShelterAddress(IAnimalShelter<IDomesticAnimal> nonDescriptShelter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nonDescriptShelter.Address as string);
    }
}
```

**What I tried:**

Manual cast:

```
PrintShelterAddress((IAnimalShelter<IDomesticAnimal>)new House() { Address = "MyHouse" });
```

Compiles but as expected, throws a run-time exception: Unable to cast object of type 'House' to type 'IAnimalShelter`1[IDomesticAnimal]'.

**What else I tried:**

```
static void PrintShelterAddress(dynamic nonDescriptShelter)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nonDescriptShelter.Address);
}
```

This works but I am not keen on using `dynamic`.

**My best solution:**

Adding an non generic base interface to `IAnimalShelter<T>` and using that:

```
public interface IAnimalShelter { String Address { get; set; } };
public interface IAnimalShelter<T> : IAnimalShelter where T : IDomesticAnimal { };

static void PrintShelterAddress(IAnimalShelter nonDescriptShelter) { ... }
```

**So...**

Is there a better solution than using `dynamic` or adding a base interface to `IAnimalShelter<T>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm.. Try to make your interfaces covariant:

```
public interface IAnimalShelter<out T> : .....
```